# Fill gap between relative and absolute div in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, styling

I need some help with this styling in Bootstrap.

```css
    .title {
      background-color:green;
    }
    
    .fill-height {
      position:relative;
      height:100vh;
    }
    .div1 {
      background-color:red;
      min-height:100px;
    }
    .div2 {
      background-color:blue;
    }
    .div3 {
      background-color:yellow;
      min-height:50px;
      width:100%;
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 title">
             Lorem Ipsum
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row fill-height">
            <div class="col-xs-12 div1">
            Loren Ipsum
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 div2">
            Lorem Ipsum
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 div3">
            Lorem Ipsum
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27543/

What I need is:

1) Fill the gap between red and yellow divs with the blue div.

2) Make 2nd `row` to have full height of the rest of the screen. `100vh`doesn't works well in this case because it's not considering the height of the first `row`.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right you could use this on the blue div

```
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
height: calc(100% - 50px);
width: 100%;
```

then add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on the fill-height div.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but I forgot to say that the divs height could be changed because of the content, so using calc() with a fixed value is not a good idea in this case.

Comment: I changed height to min-height, that's make more sense

Answer (score 0):

Well you can add some style in your code may it's work for you

```
.div2 {
    height: 100%;
}
.div3 {
    bottom: -100px;
}
```

Comment: Same as I commented in the other reply: height of the other divs could change because of the content. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open in fullscreen to view the result

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.title {
  background-color: green;
}
.fill-height {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.div3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 title">
      first Row Loren Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row fill-height">
    <div class="col-xs-12 div1">
      second reow div 1 Loren Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 div2">
      Loren Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 div3">
      Loren Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same as I commented in the others reply: height of the other divs could change because of the content, I changed fixed heights to min-height.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to do it via CSS not using javascript, then the first solution that comes to my mind is using a `display: table`:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row fill-height">
    <div class="col-xs-12 title">
     Loren Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 div1">
    Loren Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 div2">
    Loren Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 div3">
    Loren Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fill-height {
    height:100vh;
    display: table;
    width: 100%; }
.fill-height:before, .fill-height:after { content: none; }
.fill-height > * { display: table-row; }
```

and you might want to

```
.title { height: 30px; }
```

or as @samisonline pointed out, using `calc` ([supported browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp)) like so:

```
.div2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   height: calc(100% - 150px);
   width: 100%; }
```

the pixels to subtract are 150 as the sum of div1 and div3 heights: no need for any `overflow: hidden`